# 'oauth.google.authorize_redirect()' returns Error 500 : 'httpx.exceptions.ConnectTimeout'

Tags: python, oauth, authlib, starlette

I'm actually working on a platform using starlette framework with authlib for Google OAuth authentification.

Since today, I get a `500 Internal Server Error` when calling `oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)` with error `httpx.exceptions.ConnectTimeout`.

I'm totally lost about this new bevahiour.
I can reproduce it using the `demo-oauth-client` repository provided by `authlib`:
https://github.com/authlib/demo-oauth-client/tree/master/starlette-google-login

app.py being :

```
import json
from starlette.config import Config
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse, RedirectResponse
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth

app = Starlette(debug=True)
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="!secret")

config = Config('.env')
oauth = OAuth(config)

CONF_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'
oauth.register(
    name='google',
    server_metadata_url=CONF_URL,
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'openid email profile'
    }
)


@app.route('/')
async def homepage(request):
    user = request.session.get('user')
    if user:
        data = json.dumps(user)
        html = (
            f'<pre>{data}</pre>'
            '<a href="/logout">logout</a>'
        )
        return HTMLResponse(html)
    return HTMLResponse('<a href="/login">login</a>')


@app.route('/login')
async def login(request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('auth')
    return await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)


@app.route('/auth')
async def auth(request):
    token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
    user = await oauth.google.parse_id_token(request, token)
    request.session['user'] = dict(user)
    return RedirectResponse(url='/')


@app.route('/logout')
async def logout(request):
    request.session.pop('user', None)
    return RedirectResponse(url='/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

And `.env` file being :

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=[REDACTED]
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=[REDCATED]
```

Any idea on this new behaviour ? i'm totally lost with it.
Thanks !!

Comment: not sure what's going on. But it seems you are block by the first step, which is fetching information from https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Try to connect this url yourself to see how long it takes?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't really know what happened. Seems to work perfecty again today.
I can access to the url without any problem.

Comment: Maybe it was the network too slow to access google when you test it.